# jQuery based revealer ad is laggy on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Heyo,

I hope you guys can help me out. I tried to build a box that holds an advertisement. The `revealer-box` (lets call it that) sits in between the content and the ad has a fixed position and sits behind the content (it can't be seen, hidden through `z-index` and `display: none`). If the `revealer-box` is visible on the screen the ad gets a `display: block`. But the only place where it is visible is at the `revealer-box`, because all other elements have a higher `z-index`. Thus the `revealer-box` works similar to a window where you look through. This was all done and not an issue. The only problem is that it is kinda laggy on mobile (Galaxy S4, Androdid 5.0.1, Chrome). It seems like it has something to do with my jQuery. Let me post it here:

```
if($(window).width() < 601) {
    showElem(".revealer-box");
} else {
    hideElem(".revealer-box");
    hideElem(".revealer-ad");
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 601) {
        showElem(".revealer-box");
    } else {
        hideElem(".revealer-box");
        hideElem(".revealer-ad");
    }
});


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( isOnScreen(".revealer-box") && $(".revealer-box").hasClass("is-active") ) {
        showElem(".revealer-ad");
        if(flgCallGA) {
            callGA.call($(".revealer-ad"));
            flgCallGA = false;
        }
    } else {
        hideElem(".revealer-ad");
    }
});

function isOnScreen(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    var elemHeight = $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function showElem(elem) {
    if( !$(elem).hasClass("is-active") ) {
        $(elem).addClass("is-active");
    }
}
function hideElem(elem) {
    if( $(elem).hasClass("is-active") ) {
        $(elem).removeClass("is-active");
    }
}
```

As you can see it is only displayed for mobile. And the `is-active`-class only gives a `display: none`. nothing more. i hope you can help me.

sincerely,

nunu

Comment: It's laggy on mobile because you do a lot of calculations on every scroll. So if you scroll down it is executed approx 20-300 times.

Comment: alright, you're right thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Stan already pointed out, the "scroll" event is fired a few hundred times on a simple scroll. Remove the event listener on scroll and add it again after a short time.

```
function addListener(){
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrolling);
}
function scrolling(){
//remove the event listener
window.removeEventListener("scroll",scrolling);

window.setTimeout(addListener,500);
}
addListener();
```